# Choice of trivialisation to see a derivation like a connection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, connections

Let $X,S$ be  $k-$schemes with $k$ a field of characteristic $p$ and let $\omega$ be a line bundle on $X$.

Let $\nabla$ be the canonical connection on $\omega$ (with $p$-curvature $0$).

Let $z$ be a local coordinate near a geometric point $x \in X$.

- How can we choose trivializations of $\omega$ so that $\nabla$ is equal to the derivation $\frac{d}{dz}$?

There is some identification that I don't understand as $\nabla: \omega \to \omega \otimes \Omega^1_{X|S}$ but $\frac{d}{dz}\in \operatorname{Der}(\mathscr O_X, \mathscr O_X)$. How can we see a derivation like a connection?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe the connection you want is $f\mapsto df = \dfrac{df}{dz} dz$ not the derivation $f \mapsto \dfrac{df}{dz}$.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMuniz. Actually in this paper, page 6 in the proof of the proposition, it is stated that the connection is equal to the derivation $\frac{d}{dz}$: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0008238.pdf

Comment: Well the only identification that makes sense is that on a trivialization of $\omega_X$ we have just the coefficient $\dfrac{df}{dz} $ of $\dfrac{df}{dz} dz$.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMuniz. I have hard time with trivialization:) Could you please advise how you see it?. If we trivialise $\nabla: \omega \to \omega \otimes \Omega^1_{X|S} \to \omega$ on a small open $U\subset X$ where $dz$ generates $\Omega^1_{X|S}|{U}$ , we get $f \to (\frac{df}{dz}\otimes dz)\to df = \dfrac{df}{dz} dz $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are talking about line bundles I will restrict myself to this case. Note that to give a trivialization of a line bundle is the same as to give a local section without zeros. Indeed a trivialization gives a commutative diagram

[image]

where $\pi_1$ is the projection on the first component. Thus $x \mapsto \psi^{-1}(x,1)$ gives a local section that does not vanish on $U$. On the other hand given a section $s$ on $U$ that does not vanish we may construct a trivialization. Since the rank of $L$ is one, every $v \in L_x$ is a scalar multiple of $s(x)$, say $v= \lambda s(x)$ then we define $v \mapsto (x, \lambda)$.

Now returning to our case we have a local section $s$ of $\omega$ and $dz$ a local section for $\Omega^1$ then $$\nabla(gs) = g\nabla(s) + s\otimes dg = \left(Ag+ \frac{dg}{dz}\right)s\otimes dz$$ 
i.e $\nabla$ corresponds under this trivialization to the map $g\mapsto Ag+\frac{dg}{dz}$.

Therefore the question is reduced to whether we can give $s$ such that $A=0$ or equivalently $\nabla(s) =0$.

This does not happen for every connection but you have a special one. I don't know this cannonical connection but I found this discussion that may be interesting to you: [Canonical connection on the Frobenius pull-back](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1892218/289217)

Comment: Thank you very much @Alan, your great answer cleared up all my confusions:)

Comment: @PerelMan I've made more precise the section vs trivialization part.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much @Alan, trivialization is very clear to me now with your help.